# JQuery checking number and put lower than others

Tags: jquery

Here is my demo code. I want to make sure that `num` never cross `num2`. The code is functioning. but a simple problem. If `num2` has `444` i cant put first value more than 4

```
$('#num').keyup(function() {
    var num = $('#num').val();
    var chk_num = $('#num2').val();
    if (num>chk_num) {
        $('#num').val(chk_num);
    }
});
```

demo code in jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/n7bbjfpw/

Comment: `If num2 has 444 i cant put first value more than 4` can provide a example ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n7bbjfpw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are comparing strings. If you want to compare both values as integers you must parse them first with the function `parseInt`.